# How to use function containing setState synchronously

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I want to use a function containing setState() synchronously

but, it's not working

here is my code

```
const [state, setState] = useState(false)

function handlerChange(someValue) {
  //validate value and that result set state
  const isValid = REGEXP.test(someValue)
  setState(isValid)
}
async function checkValue() {
  await handlerChange()
}
function handlerClick() {
  checkValue().then(()=>{
    if(state){
    //some function
  }})
}
```

above code is ommitted in many parts,

but, the gist is that i want to execute some function according to the state in handlerClick().

state is processed asynchronously.

please any advice/help

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect with the state parameter like because useState doesn't provide any callback like setState
Ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('Do something after state has changed', state);
}, [state])
```

or You may use a custom hook just for that.